# setting the timeout on a urllib2.request() call

Tags: python, urllib2

I need to set the timeout on `urllib2.request()`.

I do not use `urllib2.urlopen()` since i am using the `data` parameter of `request`. How can I set this?

Comment: to set the timeout globally, you can use `socket.setdefaulttimeout()`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Although `urlopen` does accept `data` param for `POST`, you can call `urlopen` on a `Request` object like this,

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com', data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=4)
content = response.read()
```

Comment: @MöbiusStripMall Seconds ([manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html))

Comment: Note that `timeout` does support float values. Setting it to `0.1` works as expected. Couldn't find this documented anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

still, you can avoid using urlopen and proceed like this:

```
request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com')
response = opener.open(request,timeout=4)
response_result = response.read()
```

this works too :)

Comment: What's the benefit of not using urlopen?

Comment: @jsc123: `opener` is presumably created using `build_opener()` that allows you to configure parameters for several requests e.g., here's [an opener that allows to make http requests via a tor socks5 proxy](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463620/23044). Also, you might need to create an explicit `opener` if you use multiple threads (`urlopen()` uses global data).

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the awesome [requests](http://python-requests.org)? You'll save yourself a lot of time.

If you are worried about deployment just copy it in your project.

Eg. of requests:

```
>>> requests.post('http://github.com', data={your data here}, timeout=10)
```