# Stop a blocking operation after 10 seconds?

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a Python 2.7 program that queries a website for some URL information using Mechanize. The pseudo-code is like the following:

```
for URL in urls:
   # first submit a form to query the URL...
   # then wait and parse the results:
   while 1:
      content = response.read(1024)
      # followed by some other simple parsing operations ...
```

The read() operation in the while 1 loop is a blocking, and due to network and other conditions, sometimes it runs forever. What I'm trying to achieve is to stop waiting for the read() and jump to query the next URL if the current read() operation hasn't returned after 10 seconds. How can I time the read() operation and see whether `content` is empty after 10 seconds? I'm thinking about using threads, but am not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing you're using urllib2? see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646322/setting-the-timeout-on-a-urllib2-request-call

Comment: @MikePlacentra sorry I just updated my post, I'm using Mechanize instead of urllib2. Thank you

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks. But can you elaborate a little more on how to use select in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the timeout decorator which is described here -
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/timeout-decorator

Comment: Thank you. I tried the example code on that page, but it seems that it raises an exception and halts the program when timeout occurs. Is there a way to prevent it from raising exception and halting the program on timeout?

Comment: `try` and `except timeout_decorator.TimeoutError`

Comment: You can handle the exception and continue the execution of rest of your program like this:
<pre>
`try:
        mytest()
    except timeout_decorator.TimeoutError as te:
        # do more`
</pre>
or you can fork the github repo (subject to licensing) and customize the [code](https://github.com/pnpnpn/timeout-decorator/blob/master/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py)  @ line #144 to not raise an exception but may be retry?